# Add PDF to WooCommerce Order Email only for the admin copy

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, email-attachments

I'm using the `woocommerce_email_attachments` hook but some reason I need to add some PDF attachment only for the admin copy of new order.

I know that I can trigger this hook only for new orders, and that's ok.

But I can't figure out how can I do this only for some specific recipients.
Is there a way to do this in this hook?

This is basically what I need:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'edit_woocommerce_attachments', 10, 3 );

function edit_woocommerce_attachments($attachments, $email_id, $email_object){

    if( $email_id === 'new_order'){

        if($email == 'admin@email.com') $attachments[] = get_attached_file( 612 );
        else return;
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this instead, where you check, that the email is intended for the customer or not?

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 4);
function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email($attachments, $id, $object, $email)
{
    if (!$email->is_customer_email()) {
        $terms_path = get_template_directory() . '/assets/pdfs/terms.pdf';
        $attachments[] = $terms_path;
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```